# Stop from ending program?

Tags: python

So um...I know the basics of python and right now I'm trying to make a text-based adventure game. I have this IF statement to start or exit the game but when I start the game, the program ends. I want the program to keep going but I don't know how to.

Here is my line of code:

```
if user_start == "enter":
  print("Game Started!")

elif user_start == "quit":
  sys.exit()

else:
  print("Error 4352: Invalid Input")
```

Can you please tell me if I am doing anything wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Well, after the `if` structure there's no more code.  What exactly are you expecting the application to do after that?  Whatever you want it to do, you'd write code to do it.  I guess it's not clear to me exactly what you're asking...

Comment: If you don't know what a `while` loop is, you don't yet know the basics. I recommend working through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) (again, if you have already).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. Like @David said, it's not clear what you're asking. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a structure such as a `while True` loop.

```
while True:
    if user_start == "enter":
      print("Game Started!")
      >>> I assume you have more code that goes here  <<<
    elif user_start == "quit":
      sys.exit()
else:
  print("Error 4352: Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your program to end instantly, you will need an **infinite loop**, like `while True` for example.

Here is a little example using `input()` : you can write `"quit"` to exit, or `"enter"` to have `"Game Started!"` :

```
import sys

while True:
    user_start = input("say smthing :\n")

    if user_start == "enter":
        print("Game Started!")

    elif user_start == "quit":
        sys.exit()

    else:
        print("Error 4352: Invalid Input")
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be *infinite*, consider also looping over some content while re-checking user input for whether or not to exit the loop/game/application.  But certainly a loop of some kind if one wants to repeat some logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your program terminates because there is nothing else to run any more.
You can keep your program open by adding something like:

```
input("Press Enter to continue)"
```

For the actual game you need to provide a bit more logic.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys

while True:
    user_start = input("Type 'enter' or 'quit' : ")

    if user_start == "enter":
        print("Game Started!")
        continue
    elif user_start == "quit":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Error 4352: Invalid Input")
        continue
```

**I think you want to do Something like this.**

Hope it helps

Comment: ```continue```  statement in  ```while```  loop starts the loop again. opposite is  ```break```  in this code ```continue```  is not necessary but i think you will write more logic here so use them.